# How can I update a json dictionary at various levels?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I need help updating a json -  dictionary value with variable keys.

Here is what I know works and the issue I am having.

Let’s say I do this:

```
print(my_json['convergedSystem']['endpoints'][0]['credentials'][0]['credentialElements']['username'])
```

I get back Mike
Now if I do this:

```
my_json['convergedSystem']['endpoints'][0]['credentials'][0]['credentialElements']['username'] = ‘Carol’
```

And do the same print:

```
print(my_json['convergedSystem']['endpoints'][0]['credentials'][0]['credentialElements']['username'])
```

I get back Carol

That is just how I would expect it to work.
Problem is I don’t always know what those above index keys are or how many… I can get a list of them however.
Sometimes I may need to update

```
my_json['convergedSystem']['endpoints'][0]['credentials'][0]['credentialElements']['username']
```

Other times it could be at a different level

```
my_json['convergedSystem']['credentials'][0]['credentialElements']['username']
```

Or even

```
my_json['FullSystem'][switches]['endpoints'][2]['credentials'][0]['credentialElements']['username']
```

How can I set that in code?
Again I will always have a list available to me like this:

```
['convergedSystem', 'endpoints', 0, 'credentials', 0, 'credentialElements', 'username']
```

Or whatever it happens to be at that moment.
I know I will always be looking for ['credentialElements']['username'] at some point however

Comment: You'll probably need a recursive function that traverse the dictionary. That'd be the most viable approach if you have a list of keys but no idea where or in what level they are..

Comment: Please forgive me, I am a little bit of a hack when it comes to python.
I am able to walk through the directory, that is how I am finding every instance of 'credentialElements' at any level, and how I am getting the list of each level.
I just don't know how to use that level to update the value at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json name is *my_json* and say your list is named as *keys* and you want to update the value to *your_updated_value*:

```
val = my_json  # val contains reference to your json
for key in keys[0:-1]:  # iterate till the second last level
    val = val[key]
val[keys[-1]] = your_updated_value  # update the value
```

Note that since val has the reference of *my_json*, it'll update *my_json* too.

Comment: Thank you, Abhinav
That gets me the value, which I can already get.
I am looking to be able to change that value back.
So my_json would now be updated with a new value.

Comment: For Example:
my_json['convergedSystem']['endpoints'][0]['credentials'][0]['credentialElements']['username'] = ‘Carol’

But I need the key list to be variable length values.
If it was just variable values I could do that, but the key length is different.

Something like:
my_json[my_key_list] = ‘Carol’

Comment: Almost there...
That does update the small subset.  It does not update the whole json.
So my original json has this deep down in it: 
{'username': 'admin', 'password': 'admin123'}
With your function I get {'username': 'Mike', 'password': 'V1rtu@1c3!'} 
But not part of the original json, just that small section.
I hope I am making sense.

Comment: @MikeMaliska the above code will update your original my_json. Try printing it.

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much this is just what I needed.
It is working great.
You are the man!